# Smoothness of flows

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I tried to prove this theorem using induction:
Consider the system $X(t) = F(X(t))$ where
F is $C^r$. Then the flow φ(t, X) of this system is a $C^r$ function; that is, $(∂φ/∂t)^r$ and
$(∂φ/∂X)^r$ exist and are continuous in t and X.

I know how to show it for $r=1$ but not sure how to generalize it for all $r \in \Bbb{N} $

thanks ahead